# Is there a built in way to do non floating point decimal operations in c++?

Tags: c++, math, floating-point

I think the title describes what I want well enough, but is there a way to do arithmetic on numbers with decimals without using floats?

Comment: As far as I know, all `int` types work that way. Its only `float` and `double` types which work with fractions.

Comment: But with int can't you only do operations on integers?

Comment: If you need fixed point decimal computation, for example 2 digits after decimal point, use `int` and multiply your number by **100**

Comment: @ClaytonGearhart If I'm understanding your question correctly, if your goal is to compute integers (number without a fraction; decimal point), then `int` is the way. If it gets a fraction, then it'll round it off automatically but still you can use `std::round`. Basically `int` abbreviates to `integer`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Comment: nothing built-in, but you can write your [own](https://github.com/user1095108/dpp). Should be a nice exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a built in way to do non floating point decimal operations in c++?

No, there are no fixed point arithmetic types built in C++. Only built in arithmetic types are integers, and floating point. There are no classes for representing fixed point types in the standard library either.

Comment: (Every integer type is a fixed-point type, with the point fixed at zero fraction digits.)